# location.href not working with Capybara/poltergeist

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

For one of my projects, i am using combination of Capybara and Poltergeist. 
I have a situation where instead of using form submit, i have Javascript that is changing the window location

`Ex:location.href = new_url;`

For testing i am writing a spec that triggers the search click event and opens up the new page.

Problem that i am facing is that the test cases is always failing because it is not able to find the element on the next page. And the reason is that location.href is getting ignored, new page is never getting rendered.

**My Spec code is as follows**

`visit my_home_page_path
fill_in 'search_input_box', :with => 'some_data'
click_button('search_button')`

In Javascript: the Logic is to make an AJAX call to do some work and return the new url. 
And then using location.href, i am redirecting to new page.

This totally works fine in browser but my capybara test case is failing.

I even switched to Selenium Driver to see whats going on but same problem, in test suite new page is not getting opened.

Any ideas how to handle this ?

Comment: Please show the actual step that is failing and the error you're getting, in poltergeist you can also look at page.driver.network_traffic to see what the browser is requesting

Comment: You should probably also show the JS that is triggered by clicking the button, as well as providing version numbers for capybara, poltergeist, and phantomjs

Comment: Your assertion is maybe kicking in too early (before the next page is done loading). For a start you could try delaying the assertion with an arbitrary sleep after click_button to try if that is the cause (not saying you should use sleep in tests though).